# PowerShell Script to move folders one level up and delete the previous containing folder

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-server-2008

I'm having a windows server 2008 machine on which i've a folder structure like

```
root_folder
 ...........username1
 ....................project1
 ............................category
 ....................................subproject1
 ....................................subproject2
 ....................................subproject3
 ....................project2
 ............................category
 ....................................subproject1
 ....................................subproject2
 ....................................subproject3
```

---

```
 ...........username2
 ....................project1
 ............................category
 ....................................subproject1
 ....................................subproject2
 ....................................subproject3

 ....................project2
 ............................category
 ....................................subproject1
 ....................................subproject2
 ....................................subproject3
```

---

Now here what i need to do is remove the category folder and copy its content directly under the respective project(x) folder. Somewhat like this

```
root_folder
     ...........username1
     ....................project1
     ....................................subproject1
     ....................................subproject2
     ....................................subproject3
     ....................project2
     ....................................subproject1
     ....................................subproject2
     ....................................subproject3

-----------------------------------------------------------
     ...........username2
     ....................project1
     ............................subproject1
     ............................subproject2
     ............................subproject3

     ....................project2
     ............................subproject1
     ............................subproject2
     ............................subproject3 

-----------------------------------------------------------
```

How this can be done with powershell script. Also what would be the best a powershell script or a batch file.

Comment: Have you tried to write this script yourself?  Can you post what you have?

Comment: no, i don't have knowledge of scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: I added a modification in order to also move the files present in category folder.

```
@echo off
rem Enter into Root Folder
cd \root_folder
rem Process each User Name folder
for /D %%u in (*) do (
   rem Enter into the user name folder
   cd "%%u"
   rem Process each Project
   for /D %%p in (*) do (
      rem Enter into the category of this project
      cd "%%p\category"
      rem Move all subprojects one level up
      for /D %%s in (*) do move "%%s" ..
      rem Move all files one level up
      move *.* ..
      rem Go back one level up to project folder
      cd ..
      rem Remove the now empty category folder
      rd category
      rem Go back one level up to user folder
      cd ..
   )
   rem Go back one level up to root  folder
   cd ..
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Aacini, That works awsome!!! But it fails to move the files. 
if there is any file within the project or in category folder(files and subFolders) It doesn't moves them to on level up. I might have forgot to mention it in my question. Can you please help me out with this new test condition.

Comment: @rohitj: Modification added! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I had approximately the same problem. I wrote something like this:

```
$category_list = Get-ChildItem *\*\*

Get-ChildItem *\*\*\* | % { Move-Item $_.FullName (($_.Parent).Parent).FullName }

$category_list | Remove-Item -Recurse
```