# Script to move sub-sub-folders one level up (Batch or PowerShell)

Tags: batch-file, powershell

I have found a few similar problems on Stackoverflow, and after trying out the solutions, my problem remains unsolved.

Here is my directory structure:

> D:\XYZ\Adam Jay\Adam Jay\files.txt
>
> D:\XYZ\Adam Jay\Adam Jay\SomeFolder\
>
> D:\XYZ\Adam Jay\Adam Jay\OtherFolder\Some File.doc
>
> D:\XYZ\Mary Poppins\Mary Poppins\myOtherFile.txt

and I have about 2000 of these.

My goal is to simply cut out the redundant sub-sub folder, following the above structure. Manually, I would simply cut the "sub-sub" folder "Adam Jay" and paste it into XYZ, where-in it will replace or merge with the upper-level "Adam Jay" (moving whatever files and folders with it).

The desired result:

> D:\XYZ\Adam Jay\files.txt
>
> D:\XYZ\Adam Jay\SomeFolder\
>
> D:\XYZ\Adam Jay\OtherFolder\Some File.doc
>
> D:\XYZ\Mary Poppins\myOtherFile.txt

I have very little knowledge of batch scripts, and no knowledge of PowerShell. By modifying a script I found here on StackOverflow, I managed to mess things up (luckily, it was a test directory). [The script I played with can be found here:
[PowerShell Script to move folders one level up and delete the previous containing folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946964/powershell-script-to-move-folders-one-level-up-and-delete-the-previous-containin) ]

It would be great if anyone can help me out with this. I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Are all of the folders in question in D:\XYZ?

Comment: [Sorry, I am new to StackOverflow and only received the notification for this yesterday.]
Yes, all the folders are in D:\XYZ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd /d D:\XYZ
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /ad') do (
  if exist "%%a\%%a" (
    xcopy /E "%%a\%%a\*" "%%a"
    rd /s /q "%%a\%%a" 
  )
)
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully. Thank you very much. As for the other solution by @TheMadTechnician, I have yet to try it. This is simpler and worked well for my 3000+ folders, but I appreciate his help nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go the PowerShell route. This has two options, by default it will remove any double folders so...
Z:\XYZ\John Doe\John Doe\My Documents\Stuff\Stuff\ItsAFile.txt
becomes:
Z:\XYZ\John Doe\My Documents\Stuff\ItsAFile.txt
If you only want to get rid of the first duplicate folder comment out the 6th line, and uncomment the 7th. If you don't like the reporting part remove/comment out the Write-Output lines.

```
$BasePath = "D:\XYZ"
gci $BasePath -recurse | %{
    $OriginalFile = $_
    If($OriginalFile.PSIsContainer){$FilePath = $_.FullName.ToString().Split('\')}
    Else{$FilePath = $_.Directory.ToString().Split('\')}
    for($i=1;$i -lt $FilePath.Count;$i++){    #Comment out this line to change to Base Path +2 folders method
#    for($i=0;$i -lt $($BasePath.Split('\').Count +2);$i++){    #Uncomment to only affect the first 2 folders past the base path
        if($filepath[$i] -and ($FilePath[$i] -ieq $FilePath[$i-1])){
            $FilePath[$i-1] = $Null
        }
    }
    ($FilePath|?{$_}) -join '\'|%{
        if($OriginalFile.PSIsContainer){
            If(!($OriginalFile.FullName -ieq $_)){
            Write-Output "Moving folder $($OriginalFile.fullname) to $_"
            move-item "$($OriginalFile.fullname)\*" $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            Remove-Item $OriginalFile.fullname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
        }else{
            If(!($OriginalFile.Directory.ToString() -ieq $_)){
            Write-Output "Moving file $($OriginalFile.fullname) to $(Resolve-Path "$_\..")"
            move-item $OriginalFile.fullname "$_\.." -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }}
    }
}
```

To step through that, it:

1. Pulls a directory listing of each folder or file in the base path.
2. For each one it splits up the path based on the backslash character,
   excluding file names.
3. It then steps through each segment comparing each folder to the one
   before it in the path (or only steps the first few segments if you
   go that route).
4. If the two sequential folders match it removes the first one.
5. It then rebuilds the path at the end of that process.
6. After that it compares the modified path to the original, and if
   they are different it moves that item to the modified path.

It does handle files and folders differently, as it uses the .FullName property for folders, and the .Directory property for files.